# Combine multiple Redux RTK query hooks into single, using typescript inference

Tags: typescript, redux, type-inference, rtk-query

Assuming I have multiple results from [RTK Query hooks](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks), I want to combine their data, but keep other properties unified, for example if at least one of the hooks isLoading: true, then the final result isLoading is also true.

Ideally, I want such interface:

```js
function processSettingsOrdersData(settings: Settings, orders: Orders) { ... }

const MyReactComponent = () => {
  const settingsResult = useGetSettingsQuery()
  const ordersResult = useGetOrderSummariesQuery()


  const { 
    isLoading, 
    error, 
    data // <- combined data from both hook results using the function that was passed
  } = useCombinedResult(settingsResult, ordersResult)(processSettingsOrdersData)

...
}
```

So far I've come up with this:

```js
const useCombinedResult =
    <TResult extends UseQueryResult<any>[]>(...hookResults: TResult) =>
        <Fn extends (...args: TResult[number]['data'][]) => any>(fn: Fn) => {
            return {
                isLoading: hookResults.map(h => h.isLoading).some(Boolean),
                isFetching: hookResults.map(h => h.isFetching).some(Boolean),
                error: hookResults.map(h => h.error).find(Boolean),
                data: fn(...hookResults.map(h => h.data))
            }
        }

const settingsResult = useGetSettingsQuery()
const ordersResult = useGetOrderSummariesQuery()

const callback = (a: Settings | undefined, orders: OrderSummariesResponse | undefined) => {
    console.log({ a })
}
const combinedResult = useCombinedResult(
    settingsResult,
    ordersResult,
)(callback) // <- error callback expects both args to be same type
```

However, I realised that inferring spread arguments is not a trivial task. I wonder if it's even possible. Also the argument order doesn't really matter, passing the function first, and then expecting properly typed query result arguments would also be fine, maybe even better.